# List of tuples (begin, end) to index range (convert a pandas.IntervalArray to a numpy array?)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, sequence, intervals

## Goal

I have an array of values and a list of tuples representing which indices need to be selected from that array. (Think of tuples representing which part of an audio array is speech.) I was thinking of using a selection mask:

```py
import numpy as np

# sample data
arr = np.array([.3, .4, .5, -.2, -.1, .7, .9])
selection_idx = [(0, 3), (5,7)]

# unknown: how to efficiently selection_idx -> mask?
mask = [0, 1, 2, 5, 6]  # or
mask = [True, True, True, False, False, True, True]

# desired result 1
arr[mask]
# Out: array([0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.7, 0.9])
```

## Pandas IntervalArray approach for mask(s)

Numpy itself is limited to [`numpy.arange`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) (from what I could find) to generate regular Interval sequences. Pandas however has the [`pandas.IntervalArray`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.arrays.IntervalArray.html) object, which can be created with useful functions such as [`.from_tuples`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.arrays.IntervalArray.from_tuples.html).
In code terms that would be:

```py
import pandas as pd

pd.arrays.IntervalArray.from_tuples(selection)
# Out:
# <IntervalArray>
# [(0, 3], (5, 7]]
# Length: 2, closed: right, dtype: interval[int64]
```

### Questions

- As my use-case is outside the Pandas domain, I would like to know if it's possible to transform this `IntervalArray` object to a numpy array (resulting in `mask` under Goal)?
- If the Pandas `IntervalArray` cannot be used for my use-case, what other approach would there be? (In my real case, the list of irregular tuples is over >1000 per array (with >10.000 arrays), so I'm looking for a more efficient approach than looping and [`numpy.append`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.append.html))

Comment: Could there be interval overlaps?

Comment: @Divakar for my case, no overlap. Although I can imagine other people having benefit of seeing answers for both no-overlap and overlap situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy enough to join the respective `aranges`:

```
In [14]: np.r_[0:3,5:7]                                                                                                    
Out[14]: array([0, 1, 2, 5, 6])
In [15]: np.concatenate([np.arange(i,j) for i,j in selection_idx])                                                         
Out[15]: array([0, 1, 2, 5, 6])
```

I don't see any evidence of the `pandas` construct providing any performance benefits.  The display just looks like a lightly processed attributes from the input tuples.

===

Here's a way of constructing the mask without a loop over the itervals.  For this small case it's probably slower than my `concatenate`, but with many tuples it might be faster:

```
In [42]: idx=np.array(selection_idx)                                                                                       
In [43]: idx                                                                                                               
Out[43]: 
array([[0, 3],
       [5, 7]])
In [44]: l0=idx[:,[0]]<=np.arange(7)                                                                                       
In [45]: l1=idx[:,[1]]>np.arange(7)                                                                                        
In [46]: l0 & l1                                                                                                           
Out[46]: 
array([[ True,  True,  True, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False,  True,  True]])
In [47]: np.any(l0&l1, axis=0)                                                                                             
Out[47]: array([ True,  True,  True, False, False,  True,  True])
```

Comment: The `[(0, 3), (5,7)]` was just sample data. How would you use `np.r_` if you don't know what is in the `selection_idx`? (the real problem has a list of >1000 tuples)

Comment: Your updated approach is interesting. While `np.any(l0&l1, axis=0)` gives the Boolean mask for selecting all fragments, you can use e.g. `for single_mask in l0 & l1:` to select every fragment 1 by 1. I'm afraid it might run into memory issues, however, when `arr` is very long (e.g. 28800000 elements for a 30 min audio recording at 16kHz sample rate), because every tuple will create 2 Boolean masks (1 for l0 and 1 for l1) of `len(arr)`.

Answer (score 2):

One idea is use list comprehension with flattening:

```
mask = [c for a,b in selection_idx for c in range(a,b)]
print(arr[mask])
[0.3 0.4 0.5 0.7 0.9]
```

Answer (score 0):

This could solve your problem, although I believe there may be a syntax in Numpy that I am not aware of:

```
from itertools import chain
arr = np.array([.3, .4, .5, -.2, -.1, .7, .9])
selection_idx = [(0, 3), (5,7)]
m = list(chain.from_iterable(range(a,b) for a,b in selection_idx))

print(m)
# [0, 1, 2, 5, 6]

arr[m]
array([0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.7, 0.9])
```

Basically, it gets the list by unpacking each tuple and lumping everything into one using itertool's [chain.from_iterable](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable). All that is left is using numpy's indexing to get ur result.

Note that if you have your booleans you can use numpy's [compress](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.compress.html) to get your output :

```
mask = [True, True, True, False, False, True, True]
np.compress(mask, arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by the other answers, list comprehension with only 1 for loop to create a Boolean mask:

```py
selection_arr = np.array(selection_idx)  # convert tuples to numpy array
mask = np.full(len(arr), False)  # initialize a Boolean numpy array set to False
for b, e in selection_arr:
    mask[b:e] = True
mask
# Out: array([ True,  True,  True, False, False,  True,  True])

arr[mask]
# Out: array([0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.7])
```